# Duda captura de teclas en Python

Tags: python-3.x

estoy empezando a trastear con los juegos en python y he realizado uno muy sencillo con el modulo turtle,
No paro de inventarme nuevas cosas y ahora se me ha ocurrido meterle un esster egg que salte cuando das cierta combinacion de teclas (arriba arriba abajo abajo...),
Mi primera idea fue crear una lista donde almacenar las entradas por medio de append y luego convertirlo en cadena y hacer una busqueda del texto que resultaria al presionar esos botones ( se maneja con "w","s","a" y "d"), en la lista creada, pero no encuentro la forma.
Alguna idea?

Comment: si nos compartieras tu intento sería grandioso para nosotros :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al margen de cómo leas las letras en tu juego, voy a centrar la respuesta en cómo podrías detectar una cierta secuencia en ellas.

La idea es usar el tipo `collections.deque`. Esto es una especie de lista a la que le puedes indicar un tamaño máximo (digamos N), y a la que vas añadiendo elementos con la operación `.extend()`. Cuando se alcanza el tamaño máximo especificado (N), la próxima vez que añadas algo, se eliminará el elemento más viejo, de modo que la deque contiene siempre los últimos N elementos introducidos.

Así, si quieres detectar la secuencia "wsaddas" por ejemplo, podrías tener una deque de tamaño 7 (la longitud de la secuencia mágica) e ir metiendo en ella las teclas pulsadas. En cualquier momento puedes convertir el contenido de la deque a una cadena para compararla con "wsaddas". No necesitas buscar dentro, basta una comparación normal, pues la deque solo contendrá 7 letras como máximo.

El siguiente código implementa la idea:

```
from collections import deque

easter_egg_trigger = "wsaddas"
teclas_almacenadas = deque([], len(easter_egg_trigger))

# Bucle del juego
while True:
   ...
   tecla = leer_tecla()
   teclas_almacenadas.extend(tecla)
   if "".join(teclas_almacenadas) == easter_egg_trigger:
      show_easter_egg()
      teclas_almacenadas.clear()  # Si quieres hacer esto
   ...
   # Continuar el bucle principal del juego
```

Comment: `pynput` tenía una opción para detectar combinaciones de teclas, crees que también podría servir?

Comment: Es que no creo que se refiera a detectar combinaciones, sino secuencias. Lo típico que si primero mueves al jugador a la derecha y después abajo, saltas dos veces, caminas adelante y a la izquierda, entonces te sale un huevo de pascua.

Comment: pero esas secuencias no serían lo mismo que, por ejemplo, un combo de street fighter? Si fuese así se supone que esa secuencia debe ser hecha en un tiempo corto de tiempo y tal como esta tu código el huevo de pascua saldrá sin importar si he hecho cada acción con un intervalo de 20s.

Comment: Si, tienes razón, pero yo entendí que esto es lo que pedía el OP. A ver si lo aclara

Comment: @christian Pynput detecta pulsaciones incluso si la ventana objetivo esta minimizada. Por lo que para este escenario no serviria. Pero buena idea!

Comment: Hola a todos, @abulafia realmente me da igual que sea en un tiempo largo o corto, ya que la combinacion de teclas que le quiero poner (el codigo konami), no se deberia dar en el juego de forma casual debido a la forma en que se juega.

Comment: Perdonad si hago un uso inadecuado del foro, soy nuevo y aun no tengo muy claro como funciona

Comment: @JoseJoaquin En realidad no es un foro (es decir un lugar de conversación) sino de preguntas y respuestas, con un formato un tanto rígido. Por eso no cabe poner como respuesta algo como "gracias me ha servido". En todo caso eso debería ir a la zona de comentarios. Y la práctica habitual es marcar como aceptada la respuesta que haya dado con la solución que buscabas. Para enterarte bien de como funciona el sitio puedes leer [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

No tengo taaan claro el uso de Turtle. Pero por lo que vi, internamente usa Tkinter.

Por desgracia, Turtle no ofrece una manera de capturar una combinación de teclas. Si bien los eventos de Tkinter son más ilimitados, la función `onkey` de Turtle solo genera eventos KeyRelease. Especificamente (viendo el código fuente) usa el método bind del canvas con el evento `<KeyRelease-(la tecla pasada a onkey)>`. En mi opinión, están desperdiciando potencial en este sentido.

Pero podemos hacer nosotros mismos el bind. Al crear la cadena que representará al evento, solo hay que poner el nombre de las teclas uno al lado del otro. Por ejemplo `"wasd"`hará que se llame a una función cuando el usuario haya presionado w, a, s y d en dicho orden y sin presionar otra tecla en medio.

```
import turtle

def add_combo(screen, fun, combo):
    # si la combinación no es una tupla, la convierte en una
    if(not isinstance(combo, tuple)):
        combo = tuple(combo)

    # si dicha tupla no está en screen._keys...
    # (esto está basado en el código fuente de onkey)
    # (se espera que la lista screen._keys tenga cadenas y SUPONGO que se usa para registrar las teclas bindeadas.)
    # (en este caso pasaré la combinación como una tupla de eventos)
    if combo not in screen._keys:
        screen._keys.append(combo)

    # screen.cv nos permite acceder al canvas relacionado a screen. Este es lugar donde dibuja la tortuga.
    # Los canvas tienen el método bind, que nos permite enlazar eventos con funciones.
    # unimos todos los eventos de teclado con una cadena vacía. Por ejemplo ("w","a","s","d") se transforma en "wasd".
    screen.cv.bind("".join(combo), fun)

def poligono(event=None):
    tortuga.forward(10)

screen = turtle.Screen()
tortuga = turtle.RawTurtle(screen)

add_combo(screen, fun=poligono, combo="wasd")

turtle.listen()

turtle.mainloop()
```

Nota: Por alguna razón para evitar un pequeño bug es importante crear la tortuga del mismo modo que lo hago yo. NO usar turtle.Turtle.
Nota 2: Puede haber pasado un 20 segundos desde que presionaste la tecla w y si luego presionas el resto siguiendo los criterios antes mencionados, la tortuga se moverá.